# flask sql alchemy class method not working but works in shell

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

### Update

I wasn't able to figure out why I was getting the wrong result

but I tried something out on a whim and it worked. Although I'm not clear why.

I added a new class method changing the following

From:

```
def is_added(self, topic)
```

To:

```
def isAdded(self,topic)
```

The rest of the code stayed the same.

This is the results I see in the shell now.

```
>>> h = Highlight(text="highlight2")
>>> t = Topic(title="topic2")
>>> db.session.add(h)
>>> db.session.add(t)
>>> h.topics.all()
[]
>>> h.AddToTopic(t)
>>> h.topics.all()
[<Topic 2>]
>>> h.is_added(t)
False
>>> h.isAdded(t)
True
>>>
```

I'm guessing that there's something to do with that underscore being special in python?

but seems I can move on now.

### Original post

I have the following methods in a model called Highlight:

```
# add highlight to topic

def AddToTopic(self, topic):
   if not self.is_added(topic):
      self.topics.append(topic)


# checks if a highlight is in a topic
    
def is_added(self, topic):
  return self.topics.filter(
      topic.id == highlights_topics.c.topic_id).count() > 0
```

When I load up a shell context with the following scenario:

```
>>> h = Highlight(text="highlight1")
>>> t = Topic(title="Topic 1")
>>> db.session.add_all([h,t])
>>> h.AddToTopic(t)
>>> h.topics.all()
```

result: `[<Topic 1>]`

checking the method `>>> h.is_added(t)` I get `False`

but then I try the following:

```
>>> x = h.topics.filter(t.id==highlights_topics.c.topic_id).count() > 0
>>> x
True
```

In the shell context I'm just manually creating the same function.

why am I seeing a different result?

Additionally, if I recreate the function in the shell context, it works.

```
>>> def is_added(highlight, topic):
...     return highlight.topics.filter(topic.id == highlights_topics.c.topic_id).count() > 0
... 
>>> is_added(h, t)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your class method, instead of `self.topics.filter`, use `Highlights.topics.filter`. Use the class name instead of instance `self`.

Comment: Still getting false with is_added